# How to add comments in Struts tags?

Tags: struts2, comments

I have the following tag, how to add comments in it ?

```
<s:select id="productPrice.product" 
          name="productPrice.product"
          headerKey="0" 
          headerValue="-- Select Product --"
          list="products" 
          listKey="id" 
          listValue="name"
          value="productPrice.product.id"
          theme="simple"
          onchange="getDisplayName(value)"       <!-- How to comment here ? -->
          />
```

I've tried :

```
<!-- abc -->
<%-- abc --%>
// abc
```

None of them work, what's the correct way ?

Comment: I dont think its possible to add comment there

Comment: and reason you want to add the comments??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put the comments inside a tag. You must put them above or below the Struts2 tags. Struts2 tags are not different from HTML tags so:

- [Can XML comments go anywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824/can-xml-comments-go-anywhere)
- [HTML Comments inside Opening Tag of the Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926580/html-comments-inside-opening-tag-of-the-element)