# How do I remove a comment outside of the root element of an XML document using lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I've got some Python and I'm trying to strip all of the comments out of a variety of XML documents that I don't control. This should be capable of handling any valid XML. Here's the code so far:

```
tree = lxml.etree.parse(path_to_xml_file)
for c in tree.xpath('//comment()'):
  c.getparent().remove(c)
```

This code crashes on this particular XML file:

```
<!-- This comment can't be removed. -->
<foo>
  <!-- This comment can be removed. -->
</foo>
```

The first comment can't be removed because it has no parent element. `c.getparent()` returns `None` on that comment.  I don't see any other documentation on how to remove nodes from the XML tree. This [is valid XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50832/156767). So how can I remove this comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove all comments, use [`XMLParser`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.XMLParser-class.html) with `remove_comments=True`.

```
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_comments=True)
tree = etree.parse("test.xml", parser)
```

Answer (score -1):

It can be done if you wrap your xml with a new tag either before you parse it with lxml or after (which is not very pretty, but works as well).

Assuming you are going to do it outside lxml:

```
comt = """
<!-- This comment can't be removed. -->
<foo>
  <!-- This comment can be removed. -->
</foo>
"""

new_comt = "<super_root>"+comt+"</super_root>"
tree = etree.fromstring(new_comt)
```

and from there continue with your original code, which after

```
    print(etree.tostring(tree).decode())
```

will output:

```
    <super_root><foo>
  </foo></super_root>
```

You can then also remove the wrapping tag, if necessary.

As I said, not very elegant, but does the job.

Comment: This does not work on an XML file with an XML Declaration

Comment: clarified the question.