# How do I remove a comment outside of the root element of an XML document using python lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

How do you remove comments above or below the root node of an xml document using python's `lxml` module? I want to remove only one comment above the root node, NOT all comments in the entire document. For instance, given the following xml document

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- This comment needs to be removed -->
<root>
    <!-- This comment needs to STAY -->
    <a/>
</root>
```

I want to output

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
    <!-- This comment needs to STAY -->
    <a/>
</root>
```

The usual way to remove an element would be to do `element.getparent().remove(element)`, but this doesn't work for the root element since `getparent` returns `None`. I also tried the suggestions from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61071155/how-do-i-remove-a-comment-outside-of-the-root-element-of-an-xml-document-using-l), but the first answer (using a parser that remove comments) removes all comments from the document including the ones I want to keep, and the second answer (adding a dummy opening and closing tag around the document) doesn't work if the document has a directive above the root element.

I can get access to the comment above the root element using the following code, but how do I remove it from the document?

```py
from lxml import etree as ET
tree = ET.parse("./sample_file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
comment = root.getprevious()
# What do I do with comment now??
```

I've tried doing the following, but none of them worked:

1. `comment.getparent().remove(comment)` says `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove'`
2. `del comment` does nothing
3. `comment.clear()` does nothing
4. `comment.text = ""` renders an empty comment `<!---->`
5. `root.remove(comment)` says `ValueError: Element is not a child of this node.`
6. `tree.remove(comment)` says `AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object has no attribute 'remove'`
7. `tree[:] = [root]` says `TypeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object does not support item assignment`
8. Initialize a new tree with `tree = ET.ElementTree(root)`. Serializing this new tree still has the comments somehow.

Comment: @mzjn unfortunately that doesn't always work. There might be multiple processing instructions and doctype declarations above the root. Even the comment itself might span multiple lines.

Comment: @mzjn - I think there are a couple of options using lxml. Please see my answer below and let me know if you can think of any flaws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just build another tree by using fromstring() and passing in the root element.

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("sample_file.xml")

new_tree = etree.fromstring(etree.tostring(tree.getroot()))

print(etree.tostring(new_tree, xml_declaration=True, encoding="UTF-8", standalone=True).decode())
```

printed output...

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<root>
    <!-- This comment needs to STAY -->
    <a/>
</root>
```

Note: This will also remove any processing instructions before `root`, so another option is to append the comment to `root` before removing...

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("sample_file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for comment_to_delete in root.xpath("preceding::comment()"):
    root.append(comment_to_delete)
    root.remove(comment_to_delete)

print(etree.tostring(tree, xml_declaration=True, encoding="UTF-8", standalone=True).decode())
```

This produces the same output as above, but will retain any processing instructions that occur before `root`.

Comment: The second one is clever! It appears that appending an existing node does in fact move it. +1

Comment: Thanks! that second approach is the best way to go. I think. It deletes the exact comment node without affecting the rest of the document at all. You can even target one out of many comments above the root. I ended up creating a standalone dummy element and appending the comment node to that, instead of appending it root. That way I don't even have to remove it.

Answer (score -1):

You can parse a XML file with comments with the xmlPullParser:

If your input file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- This comment needs to be removed -->
<root>
    <!-- This comment needs to STAY -->
    <a/>
    <b>Text</b>
</root>
```

Parse the file and write it to a new one:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

# Write XML declaration line into neu file without comment 1
def write_delte_xml(input):
    with open('Cleaned.xml', 'a') as my_file:
        my_file.write(f'{input}')

with open('Remove_Comment.xml', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as xml:
    feedstring = xml.readlines()

parser = ET.XMLPullParser(['start','end', 'comment'])
for line in enumerate(feedstring):
    if line[0] == 0 and line[1].startswith('<?'):
        write_delte_xml(line[1])

    parser.feed(line[1])
    
    for event, elem in parser.read_events():
        if event == "comment" and line[0] != 1:
            write_delte_xml(line[1])
            #print(line[1])
  
        if event == "start" and r'\>' not in line[1]:
            write_delte_xml(f"{line[1]}")
            #print("start",f"{line[1]},Element: {elem}")
            
        if event == "end":
            write_delte_xml(f"{line[1]}")
            #print(f"END: {line[1]}")

# Clean douplicates
xml_list = []
with open('Cleaned.xml', 'rb') as xml:
    lines = xml.readlines()
    
    for line in lines:
        if line not in xml_list:
            xml_list.append(line)
        
with open('Cleaned_final.xml', 'wb') as my_file:
    for line in xml_list:
        my_file.write(line)
        
print('Cleaned.xml')
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
    <!-- This comment needs to STAY -->
    <a/>
    <b>Text</b>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really work for most xml files and results in an invalid file. For example, multiline comments only get their first line removed. Or, if the xml is pretty printed, there will likely be many duplicate lines for the closing tags that get removed.

Comment: You can take the branch from root, and write it to a new file, without the old declaration and comments. The double empty tags, doesn't change anything on your xml content. Why do do you need to remove the leading comments?